# Urgent: how to configure different interface using same ip subnet in asa 5506?

Tags: vlan, cisco-asa, firewall, ip-address, interface

Scenario is in old asa firewall 5505 I have switch port access vlan command in different interface. Just like below:

```
interface Ethernet0/0
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/3
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/4
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/5
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/6
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/7
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Vlan1
 nameif Outside
 security-level 0
 ip address x.x.x.x 255.255.255.224 
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif Inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 172.16.0.1 255.255.0.0
```

From above I can use different interface as same network of 172.16.0.1.

But in 5506 command is not supported. Is there any thing I can do for the same scenario I can run in 5506 asa.

Ref:

```
GigabitEthernet1/1         unassigned      YES manual administratively down down
GigabitEthernet1/2         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down
GigabitEthernet1/3         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down
GigabitEthernet1/4         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down
GigabitEthernet1/5         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down
GigabitEthernet1/6         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down
GigabitEthernet1/7         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down
GigabitEthernet1/8         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down
Internal-Control1/1        127.0.1.1       YES unset  up                    up
Internal-Data1/1           unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
Internal-Data1/2           unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
Internal-Data1/3           unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
Internal-Data1/4           169.254.1.1     YES unset  up                    up
Management1/1              unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down
```

Please help. It is urgent. Thank you.

Comment: Which command is not supported?  Please include the commands you are trying to add to your 5506.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand. You can only have one layer-3 interface in a network. The switch interfaces are layer-2 interfaces, and they are all in the network for VLAN 2. You do not assign layer-3 addresses to layer-2 interfaces.

Comment: In asa 5505 first ex. Ethernet 0/2-7 are using the same subnet of VLAN 2. This how can I enable in 5506 as switchport access vlan command is not working inside in asa 5506 in interface GigabitEthernet1/2-7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ASA 5506 doesn't have the switchport commands like the 5505. In routed mode, each interface is on a separate subnet, like a router.

Comment: But when I use the routed mode **BVI command is not supported** ? As ASA should be working in routed more then the transparent mode.

Comment: Look at this example:  https://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0001422

Comment: Thanks man. But I already looked at it. And it is only working in transparent mode. @rontrunk. So I am searching for option to do the same in routed mode.

Comment: Oh, I see now I understand what you're trying to do.  Bad news, I'm afraid.  Edited my answer.

Comment: So is there any option available to do the same or not ?

Comment: I'm afraid not.